# Center a MapView on users location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

How can I center the MapView on the current user location?

```
<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  initialRegion={region}
  style={mapStyle}
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
  showsUserLocation
  region={region}
/>
```